# Can't Parse TimeSpan with commas for separation

Tags: c#, .net, timespan

How can I send string `"0, 0, 0, 5, 0"` (d, h, m, s, f) into `TimeSpan` so it could parse it?
Input string should be exactly in this format.

It should be something like this:

```
TimeSpan ts;
var tmp = TimeSpan.TryParseExact("1, 2, 3, 4, 5", "dd, hh, mm, ss, ff", null, out ts);
// fails, tmp = false, ts = 0:00:00:00
```

I can't use `FromSecond`, `FromMinutes` etc. because it can be `"0, 15, 0, 0, 0"` or `"1, 0, 0, 0, 0"`

I can do it like this:

```
var data = ApplicationConfiguration.Instance
    .GetAppConfigValue("SavingRewardConfigurationCachingPeriod") ?? "0, 0, 0, 5, 0";

var tmp0 = new TimeSpan(
  data [0],
  data [1],
  data [2],
  data [3],
  data [4]);
```

But I'd like to find a better way to do this.

Comment: You have a piece of code in the question, but you forgot to say why it doesn't work for you

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It return me result `{00:00:00}`

Comment: @dmytro.kozyr You mean that `TryParse` returns `flase` because the format doesn't match up.

Comment: I used the format string literal `@"d\,\ h\,\ m\,\ s\,\ f"`

Comment: @AhmadIbrahim Actually `"d', 'h', 'm', 's', 'f"` will work with the original values so they don't have to manually zero pad.

Comment: Yep, as @juharr mentioned: https://dotnetfiddle.net/M7GOWR

Comment: @juharr I assume that the input values might be two-digit values, hence the format the OP used.

Comment: @AhmadIbrahim The double letter formatters require zero padding whereas the single do not, but they will work with values that have more than one digit.

Comment: @juharr you're right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to escape out the `,`  parts of the string ([as the documentation states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings#other-characters)), which is achieved by surrounding them with single quotes (`'`):

```
var tmp = TimeSpan.TryParseExact("1, 2, 3, 4, 5", "d', 'h', 'm', 's', 'f", null, out ts);
```

Example fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/M7GOWR